# Can not multiply a pandas "instance method" - how to change to float

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, instance-methods

I am using Pandas to calculate the standard deviation of a column in a data frame then multiply it by 100 to get a percentage, and then finally print it as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

results = pd.read_csv("MRAret.csv")
vol = results["Return"].std
print "Volatility: ",round(vol*100,2),"%"
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
  File "C:/Users/Stuart/Documents/SPYDER/MRA Analysis.py", line 37, in <module>
print "Volatility: ",round(vol*100,2),"%"

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'instancemethod' and 'int'
```

So obviously the "vol" variable type is an "instancemethod", which I have never come across before (I am new to Pandas).

I have tried changing the type to float using:

```
vol = float(vol)
```

but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

When I just type in "vol" into my iPython console I get the output:

```
In [95]: vol
-> vol()
Out[95]: 0.005856992616571794
```

But when I type:

```
print vol
```

I get:

```
In [96]: print vol
<bound method Series.std of 0       0.000000
1       0.004864
2       0.001604
...   
2369    0.004290
2370    0.014001
Name: Return, dtype: float64
```

I don't understand how it can be one single value and an array of values at the same time.

Could someone please explain to me how I can manipulate the vol variable of "instancemethod" type, in order to carry out arithmetic calculations.

Many thanks.

Comment: shouldn't it be `vol = results["Return"].std()`?

Comment: That did indeed sort the problem out immediately! Thank you so much. I forgot the () as I wasn't using any arguments. I'll have to remember to be less sloppy in future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error came from this typo:

```
vol = results["Return"].std
```

essentially `vol` referenced the `std` method you wanted to do this:

```
vol = results["Return"].std()
```

which is the output of that method